# Looking for a Java equivalent to JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: java, javascriptserializer

I am replacing a VB app that accesses a secure server.  My version of the app is written in Java.  The app I am replacing uses JavaScriptSerializer to encrypt the login credentials.  Is there an equivalent to JavaScriptSerializer in Java?

Comment: `com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject` ?

Comment: If understand it correctly JavaScriptSerializer creates a json object that contains the data? If yes then you could Jackson or Gson to do the same in java.